# Verification of translation of word on KPOP album

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

I recently my friend bought a KPOP album and one of the photo cards had a message on it :) I was just wondering whether I translated it right.

the message said:
항상 우리 곁에 있어줘서 고마워요~

Does this roughly translate to "thank you for always being beside us" ??

Comment: Short answer: yes

Comment: Yes! You translated it correctly! Pretty much says 'Thanks for always being with us", not exactly 'beside' but more like supporting~

Answer (score 2):

Gonna try this again because my last answer wasn’t robust enough. ㅠㅠ

The message “항상 우리 곁에 있어줘서 고마워요” roughly translates to “Thank you for being with us all the time.”

항상 = Always

우리 곁에 = beside/by us

있어줘서 = you are ('줘서' is to give, '있어' is to be; you are 'giving' your 
presence)

고마워 = thank you

But they’re not referring to literally being beside them (obviously). They’re thanking you as a fan for giving them your support in buying their album and listening to their music. In English, we similarly use the term “Thanks for standing by me”!